# Why a NOP is necessary between an Intel movl and popl?

Tags: c++, oop, compilation

I am trying to figure out a better coding of a simple accessor function in C++, using Ubuntu. Both the constructor and the Set accessor contains a NOP, which I cannot find why.

My MWE:

```
class A
{
public:
  A(void){Aa = 13;};
  int GetA(void){ return Aa;}
  void SetA(int a){ Aa = a;}
private:
  int Aa;
};

int main()
{
    A MyA;
    MyA.SetA(11);
    return MyA.GetA();
}
```

The code for the constructor, compiled by
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)
is

```
_ZN1AC2Ev:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    $13, (%eax)
    nop
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

What I cannot figure out, is that between `movl $13, (%eax)` which is an immediate to register indirect memory, and `popl   %ebp` which is stack reading (i.e. reading memory), what could be the function of the NOP? I guess it could be some memory timing trick, but I do not see any reason why a memory writing and a stack reading (i.e reading memory) could interfere (I mean: at programming level) and needs some delay. And, if it does, why at programming level?

The Set accessor is also using a NOP:

```
_ZN1A4SetAEi:
.LFB4:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    12(%ebp), %edx
    movl    %edx, (%eax)
    nop
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE4:
```

while the get accessor function itself is NOT using it:

```
    _ZN1A4GetAEv:
    .LFB3:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    (%eax), %eax
        popl    %ebp
        .cfi_restore 5
        .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE3:
```

Comment: Staring at unoptimized code is not useful, code generators make little attempt to generate optimal code.  It is the optimizer's job to make it smart code.  Many possible theories, could be the place-holder for any destructor calls but there aren't any.  Could be intentional to allow setting a breakpoint on the closing brace.  Just don't waste your time on it and only look at the /O2 code.

Comment: @Hans Passant It was just for my curiosity.  Otherwise, using -O1 or -O2, the main program simplifies to  "movl $11, %eax ; ret". Which is correct, but allows little insight into the operation of coding OOP. :)